# Limit number of displayed table rows

Tags: html, css

If I have a simple HTML table with lots of rows how can I only show `x` amount of rows?

#### HTML

```
        <table id="process-manager-table">
            <tr>
                <th>Process</th>
                <th>User</th>
                <th>CPU%</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>system-welcome.exe</td>
                <td>dvette</td>
                <td>-</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>process-manager.exe</td>
                <td>dvette</td>
                <td>-</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>process-manager.exe</td>
                <td>dvette</td>
                <td>-</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>process-manager.exe</td>
                <td>dvette</td>
                <td>-</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>process-manager.exe</td>
                <td>dvette</td>
                <td>-</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>process-manager.exe</td>
                <td>dvette</td>
                <td>-</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>process-manager.exe</td>
                <td>dvette</td>
                <td>-</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>process-manager.exe</td>
                <td>dvette</td>
                <td>-</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>process-manager.exe</td>
                <td>dvette</td>
                <td>-</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>process-manager.exe</td>
                <td>dvette</td>
                <td>-</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>process-manager.exe</td>
                <td>dvette</td>
                <td>-</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>process-manager.exe</td>
                <td>dvette</td>
                <td>-</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>process-manager.exe</td>
                <td>dvette</td>
                <td>-</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>process-manager.exe</td>
                <td>dvette</td>
                <td>-</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>process-manager.exe</td>
                <td>dvette</td>
                <td>-</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>process-manager.exe</td>
                <td>dvette</td>
                <td>-</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>process-manager.exe</td>
                <td>dvette</td>
                <td>-</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

How could I display only the first *10* rows, for example? I basically want to give my table a specific height - the user should then be able to scroll vertically within the table to view the rest of the rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking at the code provided in your JSFiddle, I have managed to modify and get this working for you:

https://jsfiddle.net/83krL60s/10/

Basically, all you need to do is put your `table` inside a `div` and set it's height.

Comment: Please describe your solution in your post so that others may benefit when searching for the same solution.

Answer (score 2):

By using the CSS `:nth-child` selector (see: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)), you can do something like this:

```
table tr:nth-child(n+12) {
  display:none;
}
```

In this case it's also picking up your table header, so it's not quite so simple as `n+10`. You could then use some javascript to adjust the value as you wish.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `style="max-height: 600px; overflow: auto; display: inline-block;"` on the table element(or surrounding DIV).  Without knowing the rendered font, It is impossible to know precisely how many lines will show up in 600 pixels(adjust accordingly), but it will give scroll bars to allow all data to be seen.

Comment: This had absolutely no effect on my table because HTML tables's do not respond to the overflow property. To solve this I added display: block; This partly worked: it set the height and overflow of table but now the table row's width don't want to be 100% no matter what I try.

Comment: @FlameStinger, Sorry, different browsers and CSS frameworks have differing default values.  I have edited my post to include `display: inline-block;` which should resolve your issues.

Comment: ..but it didn't.. you got the scroll part working great but now the table data has issues..
https://jsfiddle.net/83krL60s/5/

Comment: The problem is in your CSS not describing the td widths.  Unless specified, they adjust to the data contained within them, not necessarily filling the width of the table.

Answer (score 2):

I changed this

- add a wrapper to limit the number of displays(`max-height` and `overflow`)
- dynamic calculate offset top of the 10th table row

```js
const tr10 = ($("#process-manager-table tr:eq(10)"))[0];
const tr10OffsetTop = tr10.clientHeight + tr10.offsetTop;

$('.wrapper').css('max-height', tr10OffsetTop);
```

```css
.wrapper.overflow {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper overflow">


  <table id="process-manager-table">
    <tr>
      <th>Process</th>
      <th>User</th>
      <th>CPU%</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>system-welcome.exe</td>
      <td>dvette</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>process-manager.exe</td>
      <td>dvette</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>process-manager.exe</td>
      <td>dvette</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>process-manager.exe</td>
      <td>dvette</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>process-manager.exe</td>
      <td>dvette</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>process-manager.exe</td>
      <td>dvette</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>process-manager.exe</td>
      <td>dvette</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>process-manager.exe</td>
      <td>dvette</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>process-manager.exe</td>
      <td>dvette</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>process-manager.exe</td>
      <td>dvette</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>process-manager.exe</td>
      <td>dvette</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>process-manager.exe</td>
      <td>dvette</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>process-manager.exe</td>
      <td>dvette</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>process-manager.exe</td>
      <td>dvette</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>process-manager.exe</td>
      <td>dvette</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>process-manager.exe</td>
      <td>dvette</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>process-manager.exe</td>
      <td>dvette</td>
      <td>-</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: The OP did not tag this with JQuery.

Comment: Thank for your remind, but his problem did not mention this, and our purpose is to provide a solution to the problem, let us help him together.

Comment: I agree, your answer is superior to mine, but given a non-javascript request, I tried to answer as best I could without javascript or outside libraries. So both answers will be helpful to the OP and all who come later.