# Anuglar-Mat-Table: Display only n rows of a table - if more than with scrollbar

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

Is there a way to display only e.g. 5 rows of a `mat-table` and if the table has more than 5 rows it will displayed as scrollable?

If I take the sample from Angular Material [Tables](https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src/app/table-basic-example.ts) it displays 10 items (=rows). How to limit the output to the mentioned 5 rows and than start scrolling?

Background: I need to place the `mat-table` on a `mat-tab` element. The different panes vary little bit in height. The table could have an arbitrary number of rows. Since I know that for a proper layout just 4 (or perhaps 5) rows are fitting properly I want to limit the total height of the table.

I found solutions [like](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52396439/325868) but didn't find a way to properly apply `overflow` and `display` attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap table in `div` and add `max-height: 248px` and `overflow: auto`.

Example

```html
<div style="max-height: 248px; overflow: auto">
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
  ...
</table>
</div>
```

Why `max-height` as `248px`?
Because the row height of table data is `48` so
**48px**(each row) * **4**(rows) = 192px + **56**(Table header) = **248px**

Comment: Hmmm.... I haven't thought that it has an influence how the total layout would look like. Your suggestion works but it seems like it won't work if I place two components next to each other, i.e. to have a `mat-card` on the right side of the table. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wcpe6e?file=src/app/table-basic-example.css
Hmmm... you have an idea how to do it more appropriate? Rem.: the class `table-wrap2` should be renamed to `table-wrap` to have you suggested settings.

Comment: Wrap table and card in another div and apply `display:flex` to it, Is that what you are expecting? BTW you're question was about height and scroll isn't it? Do mention what is the desired output in question.

Comment: You are completely right - but honestly I didn't expect side effects :-/ I thought some styling for the table would be enough. Anyway thx I'll try tomorrow.

Comment: Thx for the last hint - this helps to resolve my problem completly. :-)